# Updating a dynamic control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a custom web part with Accordion panes from the AJAX Control Toolkit as children that are used to render a site map hierarchy.  Each pane includes a div with text input and 3 LinkButtons used to edit the sitemap data: "Add Child", "Update", and "Delete".

Currently, all these controls are created in the overridden CreateChildControls method.

When the "Add Child" LinkButton is clicked, the event handler is fired, and a new node is added to the sitemap.  When the postback completes, the control should re-render with the new, empty node in the hierarchy, but it doesn't.  After a new GET request, the new node appears.  After reading for a while, I thought my problem was that I was creating my child controls too early in the process because CreateChildControls is called before Control events are fired, so I moved that bit to the OnPreRender method.  But now the Control events don't fire because I'm hooking them up too late in the Page lifecycle (see here: [Custom Control Events Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471260/custom-control-events-not-firing)).

My question is this: how do I ensure that the custom control renders the results of its child control event handlers?

As an aside, does it matter that I'm doing this in a web part rather than a custom server control (e.g., is the lifecycle different)?

Answer (score 1):

You could call EnsureChildControls in OnInit of the page.  This will ensure that child controls will be recreated before any events are handled.